# WP Dropdown Categories, display subcategories but not grandchildren categories?

Tags: plugin-development, dropdown, categories

So my main goal is to create 3 drop-down category options to run a search. It's for a car website, so I have 3 parents, "Make", "Model", and "Year"

At the moment I have the following code

```
<?php $args = array('show_option_none' => 'Make', child_of => 5,hide_empty => '0',exclude => '0'); ?>
<b>Make  </b><?php wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>

<?php $args2 = array('show_option_none' => 'Model', hide_empty => '0',exclude => '0'); ?>
<b>Model  </b><?php wp_dropdown_categories($args2); ?>

<?php $args3 = array('show_option_none' => 'Year', hide_empty => '0',exclude => '0'); ?>
<b>Year  </b><?php wp_dropdown_categories($args3); ?>
```

I plan on creating an if statement for the "Models" so it changes based on the "Make" selection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mno4.png

How can I remove grandchildren from the "Make" drop-down? At the moment it shows the Car makers and the models underneath.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To remove grand-children:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'show_option_none' => 'Make', 
    child_of => 5,
    hide_empty => '0',
    exclude => '0',
    hierarchical => 1,
    depth => 1
    ); ?>
<b>Make  </b><?php wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
```

You need to add the hierarchical and depth parameters.